# Test Performance of Symfony2 Container / Kernel

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I am using LiipfunctionalBundle for most of my testcases, even if they are unit. Just because of the "convenience" methods in there. Recently I realized that my test performance is really bad, even for single unit tests of services.

This issue araises mainly if I get my services from the container. Which in the LiipTestBundle requires the creation of the Kernal and booting it:

```
protected function getContainer()
{
    if (!empty($this->kernelDir)) {
        $tmpKernelDir = isset($_SERVER['KERNEL_DIR']) ? $_SERVER['KERNEL_DIR'] : null;
        $_SERVER['KERNEL_DIR'] = getcwd().$this->kernelDir;
    }

    $cacheKey = $this->kernelDir.'|'.$this->environment;
    if (empty($this->containers[$cacheKey])) {
        $options = array(
            'environment' => $this->environment
        );
        $kernel = $this->createKernel($options);
        $start = microtime(true);
        $kernel->boot();
        $time = microtime(true) - $start;
        print('boot:'.$time.PHP_EOL);

        $this->containers[$cacheKey] = $kernel->getContainer();
    }

    if (isset($tmpKernelDir)) {
        $_SERVER['KERNEL_DIR'] = $tmpKernelDir;
    }

    return $this->containers[$cacheKey];
}
```

In some of my cases this booting in "test" environment takes 6-10s. Sometimes only 2s. But it is still very slow and I would like to know why this is so slow and what I could do about it. I already started creating services in my testcases on my own instead of using the container. But that also means more effort for creating test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "convenience" is killing you. You should only use the LiipfunctionalBundle with **functional tests**. Following your current path, you'll soon also find your tests hard to maintain.

If you want quick tests, write more unit tests. Use dependency injection properly. Don't inject the container into your classes (i'm only guessing WHY you chose to use the kernel or container in your tests).

In *dev* and *test* environments resources are monitored, so that if a config file changes, the cache is refreshed. That's most likely the reason why it's slower than *prod* environment.